# In Xcode, how can I utilize new UI APIs for Yosemite, but then revert to older ones for older OS'?

Tags: xcode

I have been looking all over the place and can't seem to find an answer. (I'm probably not using the correct terminology)

I'm building a simple AppleScript ObjC program and I want to use the new UI API for Yosemite (NSVisualEffectView) but, as expected, it crashes when I open it on Mavericks. How could I get it to use old APIs instead without having to create a completely different app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to figure out at runtime if method/class is available. Here's Apple guide about ["SDK Based Development"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002000-SW6).

In Your case It'll look like this:

```
if ([NSVisualEffectView class])
{
    // OS X 10.10 code here.
}
else
{
    // OS X < 10.10 code here.
}
```

Comment: My apologies if these questions are extremely basic. In this block, would I be entering the raw code for the windows themselves (instead of using IB), or could I have a call at runtime look for either the vibrancy.xib or nonVibrancy.xib?

Comment: @ElRojito You can enter raw code here, or override `initWithNibName:bundle:` method and swap xibs using this `if` statement.